# shutil.copytree to NAS hangs in python

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to use shutil.copytree in Python 3.9.5 to backup a code root directory from a PC to a local NAS. The backup works (backup folder created with all contained files), but then the code hangs for about 15-30 minutes.  No copying is happening during this time - the files are copied quickly.  No windows errors are thrown.  I am running threads.

Has anyone seen this behaviour, or can suggest a fix/workaround? I see a bug reported here: https://bugs.python.org/issue21885 from 2017 but no solutions.

```
def backupCode():
import shutil

file_path = 'X:\\DestinationParentFolder'
folder_name = f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')}"

try:
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(file_path, folder_name)):
        print("Backing up Python code...", end="")
        shutil.copytree('C:\\Users\\fatgecko\\PycharmProjects\\Code_Folder', os.path.join(file_path, folder_name)) 
       #Execution pauses here for 15-30 minutes
        print(f"\r Python code backed up to {os.path.join(file_path, folder_name)}.")
        
except Exception as e:
    print(f"\nCould not backup python code: {e}")
```

Comment: ```if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(file_path, folder_name))```, maybe in that 15 - 30 minutes, it encounters files

Comment: Thanks Sujay. `if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(file_path, folder_name))` is just checking for the presence of a single folder; the code passes that line no problems because it executes the next two lines (print & shutil.copytree) before then hanging.